# アプリをホームボタン二回押しで終了しても、処理が継続されるようにしたいです。

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

XcodeでObjective-Cで開発してます。
ボタンを押すと数字が増えるという簡単なアプリを作っているのですが、アプリを消すと、数字のカウントが初期値に戻ってしまいます。
これを、アプリを落としても継続されるようにするにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？

ソースコードを下記に記載しておきます。

**CounterViewController.h**

```
IBOutlet UILabel *display; 
int count; // 変数の宣言 

- (IBAction)add;
```

**CounterViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)add { count = count + 1; display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", count]; }
```

Comment: 「ホームボタン二回押しで終了」と書いてあるので、iOSアプリのことだろうとわかりますが、やはりタグでiosも指定しておいた方が良いでしょう。また「ボタンを押すと数字が増えるという簡単なアプリ」と言うことですが、それだけのアプリでも「数字のカウント」をどう保持するのかいくらでも方法は考えられます。現在のあなたのコード(メインのViewControllerの.hと.m両方)を示すことはできませんか。簡単なアプリならコード全体を載せてもそれほど大きくはならないかと思います。ご自身の質問は編集できるはずですので、是非ご掲載をお願いします。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
ご指摘の通り、ソースコードを記入致します。

CounterViewController.h
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *display;
    int count;          // 変数の宣言
}
 - (IBAction)add;




CounterViewController.m
 
- (IBAction)add {
    count = count + 1;
    display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", count];
}

です。

引き続き、ご回答よろしくお願いします。

Comment: すみません。コメントだと改行が出来ないみたいで、改めて質問を投稿し直します。お手数をおかけしてすみません。
http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/26708/再掲載-アプリをホームボタン二回押しで終了しても-処理が継続されるようにしたいです

Comment: ご自分の質問を表示すると「編集」と言うのが見えないでしょうか。コメントで「〜〜の情報が必要」と言われた場合、「編集」をクリックしてご自分の質問の中に新しい情報を追記するようにしてください。新しいご質問の方に回答が付いていますので、こちらは削除してしまわれた方が良いでしょう。(「削除」&「再投稿」は本来勧められるやり方ではないのですが。)ちなみに、新しい質問の方もコードの部分が見難くなっています。このサイトの「コード引用」の仕方を覚える意味でも、できればご自分で編集して、コードの部分をうまく見せるやり方を覚えてください。

Comment: 「再投稿」の方がクローズされて、こちらを編集してコードを掲載されたようですので、こちらに回答しておきます。

Comment: 役に立った回答を承認していただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

さて、あなたのコード例のようにカウント値をインスタンス変数として保持するのであれば、基本は:

- アプリが終了する前にそのインスタンス変数の値を保存する
- アプリが起動する時に、保存された値があれば、それをインスタンス変数にセットする

と言った処理を追加することになります。
(現在のiOSのViewControllerには、状態の保存／復元を行う便利な機能があるのですが、「ホームボタンを二回押しで終了」した場合には働きません。「ユーザが意図的にアプリを強制終了した場合は、次回は初期状態から起動するべき」と言うのがAppleの考え方なのでしょう。本格的なアプリ作成に進まれるのなら、考慮した方が良いかもしれません。)

あなたのコードの場合、カウント値はViewControllerのインスタンス変数になっているので、「アプリが終了する前」は`viewWillDisappear:`、「アプリが起動する時」は`viewWillAppear:`で捉えるのが簡単でしょう。

CountViewController.mにそれら2つのメソッドを追加してください。

```
#define MyViewControllerCount @"MyViewControllerCount"

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    //ViewControllerが表示される前に、保存された値があるかどうかをチェックする
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if( [defaults objectForKey:MyViewControllerCount] ) {
        count = (int)[defaults integerForKey:MyViewControllerCount];
    } else {
        count = 0;
    }
    display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", count];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    //ViewControllerが消える前に値を保存する
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setInteger:(NSInteger)count forKey:MyViewControllerCount];
}
```

なお、ここでは保存する値が整数値1件だけでしたので`NSUserDefaults`を使いましたが、アプリで状態保存を行う場合、別に「必ず`NSUserDefaults`を使う」と決まっているわけではありません。アプリが発展してデータ構造やデータ量が増えた場合には、Core Dataや独自アーカイブなども検討した方が良いでしょう。

---

コメントでいただいた`UIButton`の`hidden`属性も保存したいという件ですが、コメント中に書いたように「Vi‌​ewControllerの状態保存／復元は`viewWillDisappear:`と`viewWillAppear:`が使える」と言う点は変わりません。上に示したコードにちょっと付け足して、例えばこのようにすれば、`hidden`状態も保存できると思いますが、いかがですか？

```
#define MyViewControllerCount @"MyViewControllerCount"
#define MyViewControllerButtonHidden @"MyViewControllerButtonHidden"

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    //ViewControllerが表示される時に、保存された値があるかどうかをチェックする
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if( [defaults objectForKey:MyViewControllerCount] ) {
        count = (int)[defaults integerForKey:MyViewControllerCount];
        //MyViewControllerCountのデータがあれば、MyViewControllerButtonHiddenもあるはずなんでチェックは省略
        //_countButton.hiddenを復元
        _countButton.hidden = [defaults boolForKey:MyViewControllerButtonHidden];
    } else {
        count = 0;
    }
    display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", count];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    //ViewControllerが隠されてしまう時に値を保存する
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setInteger:(NSInteger)count forKey:MyViewControllerCount];
    //_countButton.hiddenを保存
    [defaults setBool:_countButton.hidden forKey:MyViewControllerButtonHidden];
}
```

アプリを実用的なものに近づけていくと、どんどん保存すべき状態が増えていくことと思います。`NSUserDefaults`は、あくまでも数十件以下の単純な数値や短い文字列を保存する場所と割り切って、アプリが大規模になって来た時には発想を変えられるようにしておいてください。

Comment: Le Pere d'OOさん
ありがとうございます。カウント追加した値の保存、出来ました！

また、大変恐縮なのですが、データ保存についてもう一つご質問させて頂いてよろしいでしょうか？

別ボタンを追加して、一定のカウントに達すると、数値を増やすボタンを消したいと思っております。

-(IBAction)hidden:(id)sender{
    _countButton.hidden = YES;
}

この状態も同様にアプリを落としても継続されるようにするにはどのように記載したらよろしいでしょうか。

何度も申し訳ないのですが、もしよろしければご教授頂けましたら幸いです。
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 「アプリが終了する前にそのインスタンス変数の値を保存する」「アプリが起動する時に、保存された値があれば、それをインスタンス変数にセットする」と言う基本と、「ViewControllerの状態保存／復元は`viewWillDisappear`と`viewWillAppear`が使える」と言うちょっとした応用、それに`NSUserDefaults`の使い方がわかれば、本当にほとんど同じことを繰り返すだけですよ。コメントにはコードは書きづらいので、後で回答に追記しておきますからご覧ください。なお、Q&Aサイトでは同じ質問の重複投稿と同じくらい「いろんな話が混ざっていて何を聞きたいのかわからない」のも避けた方が良い事柄です。今回は今書いたように強い関連性があるから良いですが、「さらに造り込んでいったら全く別の問題が出た」と言った場合は新たに別質問のスレを立ててください。

Comment: Pere d'OOさん　度々ありがとうございます！hiddenの設定も出来ました。やりたいことが全部できました。また、ソースコードももちろんですが、この掲示板の使い方まで親切にありがとうございました。運営者や他の利用者にまでご迷惑をおかけしてすみません。今後もプログラミング学習を続けていきたいと思っておりますので、色々と学ばせてもらいたいです。